# Create an arrow with a line in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a work flow for which I need an arrow between the steps. I have created a line between the steps using the pseudo element :after on the step div but have no idea how to put an arrow head at the end of the line. I have written the following code till now.`

```css
.step-items {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
}

.steps {
    margin: 1em;
    border-radius: 10%;
    height: 5em;
    padding: 1rem;
    width: 7rem;
    height: 4rem;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #00abff, #45e5c3);
}

.steps:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    width: 22%;
    top: 2em;
    left: -2em;
    color: #00abff;
    background-color: #00abff;
}

.steps:first-child::after {
    content: none;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="step-items">
  <div class="steps">
    Item 1
  </div>

  <div class="steps">
    Item 2
  </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle to the current code](https://jsfiddle.net/prasadvaibhav/z157kfor/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added

```
.steps:first-child::before {
    content: '▶︎';
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    left: calc(100% + 36px);
    color: #00abff;
    top: 8px;
}
```

to your css. I think it should do what you're trying to do.

Link to edited fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z157kfor/4.

Suggestions for improving your current code:

- Rather than setting an `::after` on `.steps` and then hiding the `::after` on the first child, add the `::after` to `:nth-child(2)`.
- I think it's more intuitive to add both the arrow's body and the arrow head as pseudo-elements on the same element (ideally the first, since arrows are usually drawn from the origin to the destination).

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding a simple arrow using the content attribute but it's not quite aligned.
Hope it helps.

```
.steps:after {
  content: ">";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 22%;
  top: 2em;
  left: -2em;
  color: #00abff;
  background-color: #00abff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it won't look good. Though I will try to do something with the code you gave. Thanks

Answer (score -4):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Line arrow</title>
<style type="text/css">
.box {
    width: auto;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 4em 20px;
    border: 1px dashed;
    position: relative;
}

.line-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px; /*set the size for arrow*/
    width: 4em;
   height: 4em;
    margin-top: -2em;
    top: 50%;
}

.line-arrow.left {
    border-top: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
   border-left: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
    transform: rotate(-54deg) skew(-20deg);
    left: 20px;
}

.line-arrow.right {
   border-top: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
   border-right: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
    transform: rotate(54deg) skew(20deg);
    right: 20px;
}

.line-arrow:active,
.line-arrow.active {
    border-width: 2px;
}

.square {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.square.left {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.square.right {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="box">
    <a class="line-arrow left active" href="javascript:;"></a>
  <p style="background-color:red"><marquee behaviour="scroll" onmouseover="this. stop()" onmouseout="this. start()" >Md Rakibul hasan</marquee></p>
    <a class="line-arrow right" href="javascript:;"></a>
      <a class="line-arrow square left" href="javascript:;"></a>
      <a class="line-arrow square right" href="javascript:;"></a>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Try this .................

Comment: I know how to create arrow heads, I don't want this.